# All fileds of the net_device_stats structure is returned zero

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wrote a simple Linux kernel module in C to return `rx_bytes` and `tx_bytes` but all values is returned zero

```c
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/module.h> 
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/netdevice.h>
    #include <linux/delay.h>

    static int mymodule_init(void)
    {   
        struct net_device *dev = first_net_device(&init_net);   

        // struct net_device *my_net_device;
        // struct net *my_net;
        // struct dev_net *my_dev_net;
        struct net_device_stats *stats;

        while (dev) {
            printk("Dev: name: %s - ifindex: %d\n", dev->name, dev->ifindex);
            if (netif_running(dev)) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Device is up\n"); 
                printk(KERN_INFO "      Device name %s\n", dev->name);
                printk(KERN_INFO "              MTU %d\n", dev->mtu);
                printk(KERN_INFO "      Dev Address %pM\n", dev->dev_addr);
                printk(KERN_INFO "Permanent Address %pM\n", dev->perm_addr);
                msleep(1000);
                stats = &dev->stats;
                printk(KERN_INFO "          rx_bytes %llu\n", (unsigned long long) stats->tx_heartbeat_errors);
            } else { 
                printk("Device is down\n"); 
            }
            
            if (test_bit(__LINK_STATE_NOCARRIER, &dev->state)) 
                printk("NOCARRIER set\n"); 
            else 
                printk("NOCARRIER NOT-set\n"); 

            /* Access the rx_bytes field of the network statistics */
            dev = next_net_device(dev);
        }

        return 0;   
    }

    static void mymodule_exit(void)
    {
    }

    module_init(mymodule_init);
    module_exit(mymodule_exit);

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
    MODULE_AUTHOR("Kiavash Rocky");
    MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Read device structure of a given device file");
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.1 64-bit Kernel 5.15.0-69-generic

OS installed on Virtual Machine.

Output:

```auto
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel: Dev: name: lo - ifindex: 1
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel: Device is up
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel:       Device name lo
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel:               MTU 65536
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel:       Dev Address 00:00:00:00:00:00
Apr 16 20:35:50  kernel: Permanent Address 00:00:00:00:00:00
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel:           rx_bytes 0
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel: NOCARRIER NOT-set
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel: Dev: name: ens3 - ifindex: 2
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel: Device is up
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel:       Device name ens3
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel:               MTU 1500
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel:       Dev Address fa:16:3e:76:37:3d
Apr 16 20:35:51  kernel: Permanent Address fa:16:3e:76:37:3d
Apr 16 20:35:52  kernel:           **rx_bytes 0**
Apr 16 20:35:52  kernel: NOCARRIER NOT-set
```

The traffic is not zero but all values is returned zero.

Comment: These data fields are in the CPU-aware variables as far as I remember. If my memories are correct, you must use special CPU variable accessors and sum all of them over all CPUs (even that are not running at the moment).